# Very steep decrease in information criteria for mixture models with more components

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I am analyzing data using mixture modeling. When I plot the information criteria (the BIC) for a series of models (with different *model specifications* and *different number of mixture components*), I notice a very steep decrease in the BIC. E.g., in the photo below, the fitted model represented by the grey lines (and points) with five profiles (or components) has a much lower BIC than that with four components (the BIC decreases by around 50%). Similar for the model represented by the red line between five and six mixture components.

Is this a cause for concern? Or is it likely that this is due to real improvements in the model fit when an additional component is added? It seems like a change of this magnitude, all other things being equal, is cause for concern. What would you to do to follow-up on this analysis to determine whether the change in the log-likelihood is spurious and problematic or indicative of (practically) meaningfully better fitted models?

[image: BIC values for different solutions]

Comment: I don't understand what the different colored lines are.  Please clarify.  Imagine that you clearly separate 5 clusters of points.  If you use a 2-component mixture and you do some decent housekeeping you either get 2 mixtures with 2.5 components or you get 1 with 3 and 1 with 2.  If, however you increase to 5, then at five it "clicks".  That can happen.  Don't assume it is happening.  Test it.  There are good ways to do that.

Comment: Just edited the plot to show what they were (different parameterizations of the model). Two questions. 1) What do you mean by 2 mixtures with 2.5 components (or 1 with 3 and one with 2)? I may be misunderstanding the difference b/w mixture and component. 2) How would you test the situation you described? Thanks. Feel free to add in an answer.

Comment: What can you tell me about the nature of your data?  Is there a standard data (iris, crab, ...) that captures the important features of your actual data?  How many dimensions (columns) and samples (rows)?

Comment: Thanks. The data are five variables that can take values from 1-4. There are 3,000-ish rows. The data are (mostly) normally distributed. They're pretty correlated (r = .3-.5-ish). I can share more (or share the data), too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get fractional membership.

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(1)

mu1 <- c(0,0)
sig1 <- matrix(data=c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)

mu2 <- c(3,4)
sig2 <- matrix(data=c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)

mu3 <- c(9,4)
sig3 <- matrix(data=c(1,0.1,0,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)

mu4 <- c(12,0)
sig4 <- matrix(data=c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)

mu5 <- c(6,-3)
sig5 <- matrix(data=c(1,0.1,0.1,1), nrow=2,ncol=2)

x1 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu1, Sigma = sig1)
x2 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu2, Sigma = sig2)
x3 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu3, Sigma = sig3)
x4 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu4, Sigma = sig4)
x5 <- mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mu5, Sigma = sig5)


x <- rbind(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
y <- rbind(rep.int(1,times = 1000),
           rep.int(2,times = 1000),
           rep.int(3,times = 1000),
           rep.int(4,times = 1000),
           rep.int(5,times = 1000))

c2 <- kmeans(x=x,centers = 2)

plot(x)
grid()
idx <- which(c2$cluster==1)
points(x=x[idx,1],y=x[idx,2], pch=19, col="Green")
points(x=x[-idx,1],y=x[-idx,2], pch=19, col="Red")
```

Yielding:

[image]

So here is code to estimate AIC (a cousin of BIC):

```
kmeansAIC = function(fit){

     m = ncol(fit$centers)
     n = length(fit$cluster)
     k = nrow(fit$centers)
     D = fit$tot.withinss
     return(D + 2*m*k)
}


my_bic <- numeric(length = 10)
for(i in 1:10){
     c2 <- kmeans(x=x,centers = i)
     my_bic[i] <- kmeansAIC(c2)

}

plot(log10(my_bic))
points(5,log10(my_bic[5]), pch=19, col="Red")
```

and here is the result:

[image]

This is why I like the "[scree plot](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_sub/spss/tutorials/fac_cars_scree_01.html)" approach.  I know it is 5 clusters.  You know it is 5 clusters.  Looking at the differences, the 5-component model is indicated.